# Python 3: Check if a string is an import command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check a string - is it an import command? I have tried

```
# Helper - analyses a string - is it an import string?
"""
fromlike   - from foo import bar
classic    - import foo
classic_as - import foo as baz
"""
def check_is_import(string):
    importname = ''
    fromlike   = False
    classic    = False
    classic_as = False
    if string[0:4] is 'from':
        fromlike = True
        importname = ''
    if not fromlike and (string[0:6] is 'import'):
        classic = True
        importname = string.split(' ')[1]
    if classic:
        commandlist = string.split(' ')
        if commandlist[2] is 'as':
            classic_as = True
            importname = commandlist[3]
            del commandlist
    if fromlike:
        return ('fromlike', importname)
    elif classic and (not classic_as):
        return ('classic', importname)
    elif classic_as:
        return ('classic_as', importname)
    else:
        return ('no_import', importname)
```

but it worked for "fromlike" imports. (Note: I'm not asking "why does this code don't work?", I'm just searching a solution) What code will sure detect all imports? Basically my code takes a slice of the string. If the `[0:4]` slice equals `'from'`, the string is a "fromlike import". Else: if the `[0:6]` slice equals `'import'`, the string is a "classic import". If it detects `'as'`, it will find the pseudo-name. This function must return a tuple which contains the import type under index 0 and imported module-name under index 1.

Comment: Why have a dog and bark yourself? Use [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) and look at the resulting AST tree.

Comment: @MartijinPieters Please give me an example.

Comment: In the process of writing an answer. :-)

Comment: What should happen for multiple names? `import foo, bar, baz as spam`?

Comment: Same as importing them as separate `import` commands, but returns `('classic_multi_as', 'spam')`

Comment: That makes no sense. There are three names there. `foo`, `bar` and `spam`. Only the last name is an `classic_as` import, the first two are straight up `classic`.

Comment: And `(('classic, 'foo'), ('classic, 'bar'), ('classic, 'baz'))` for `import foo, bar, baz`

Comment: So now you have a sequence. For 'no import' you should return an empty sequence or raise an exception then.

Comment: And I'd use a list, not a tuple, in that case. Tuples are for fixed-length mixed types (two elements with type and value, for example), lists for variable-length homogenous types (a list of tuples, for example).

Comment: There is also `from foo import baz as spam, bar, monty as spam`, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure to handle all Python import forms, have *Python do the parsing*. Use the [`ast.parse()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) and use the resulting parse tree; you'll either get `Import` or `ImportFrom` objects:

```
  | Import(alias* names)
  | ImportFrom(identifier? module, alias* names, int? level)
```

Each `alias` consists of a name and optional identifier used to import the name *as*:

```
-- import name with optional 'as' alias.
alias = (identifier name, identifier? asname)
```

Note that there can be *multiple imports*! You either have `classic` or `fromlike` imports, and both can import multiple names. Your function needs to return a **list** of `(type, name)` tuples. For invalid inputs, raise an exception (`ValueError` is a good fit here):

```
import ast

def check_is_import(string):
    try:
        body = ast.parse(string).body
    except SyntaxError:
        # not valid Python
        raise ValueError('No import found')
    if len(body) > 1:
        # not a single statement
        raise ValueError('Multiple statements found')
    if not isinstance(body[0], (ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom)):
        raise ValueError('No import found')
    type_ = 'classic' if isinstance(body[0], ast.Import) else 'fromlike'
    results = []
    for alias in body[0].names:
        alias_type = type_
        if alias.asname:
            alias_type += '_as'
        results.append((alias_type, alias.asname or alias.name))
    return results
```

The method should probably be renamed to `extract_import_names()`, as that reflects what it does much better.

Demo:

```
>>> check_is_import('from foo import bar')
[('fromlike', 'bar')]
>>> check_is_import('import foo')
[('classic', 'foo')]
>>> check_is_import('import foo as baz')
[('classic_as', 'baz')]
>>> check_is_import('from foo import bar, baz as spam, monty as python')
[('fromlike', 'bar'), ('fromlike_as', 'spam'), ('fromlike_as', 'python')]
>>> check_is_import('import foo as baz, baz, spam as ham')
[('classic_as', 'baz'), ('classic', 'baz'), ('classic_as', 'ham')]
>>> check_is_import('invalid python')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in check_is_import
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    invalid python
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in check_is_import
ValueError: No import found
>>> check_is_import('import foo; import bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in check_is_import
ValueError: Multiple statements found
>>> check_is_import('1 + 1 == 2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in check_is_import
ValueError: No import found
```

Comment: Error! Explained in the question.